# How do I find out a keyword in a range of a excel in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I  have a excel file, I wanna search from A1 to A27 and find out which cell have keyword called 'currency'.

How do I do this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using hExcel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace excel004
{
   class Program
   {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xls_path = "c:\\sample.xls";
            hExcel.Application xlsApp = new hExcel.ApplicationClass();
            hExcel.Workbook xlsWorkbook = xlsApp.Workbooks.Open(
                xls_path,   //file name
                0,          //UpdateLinks
                true,       //read-only
                5,          //Format
                "",         //password
                "",         //write password,
                true,       //IgnoreReadyOnblyReconnected
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, //Origin
                "\t",       //Delimiter
                false,      //Editable
                false,      //Notify
                0,          //Converter
                true,       //AddToMru,
                1,          //Local
                0           //CorruptLoad
            );

            hExcel.Worksheet xlsWorksheet = (hExcel.Worksheet)xlsWorkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);


            // Output Worksheet properties
            hExcel.Range xlsRange = xlsWorksheet.UsedRange;
            int columns = xlsRange.Columns.Count;
            int rows = xlsRange.Cells.Rows.Count;
            Console.Write("[info]Worksheet columns: "+columns+"\n");
            Console.Write("[info]worksheet rows: " + rows + "\n");

            // Find Keyword: Currency
            //(1)set range
            // I stopped here, coz I don't how to search from A1 ~ A27 with keyword:currency
              Console.Write(xlsWorksheet.get_Range("A1", "A27").Value2.ToString()); //get nothing 
           // my excel file is Row:100 * Column:20.
           // if the way have to look up all the cells,
           // i will give up to ask this question, 
           // I think it should be a way just look up one column that's A1 to A27.

           // [Resolved 1:] Answer from Francesco Baruchelli
            hExcel.Range titleRange = xlsWorksheet.get_Range("A1","A27");  //it works

           // [Resolved 2:] it works, but not good, coz it get too many unused value
            hExcel.Range titleRange = (hExcel.Range)xlsWorksheet.Columns.get_Item(1,Type.Missing);  
           // why this is wrong? 
           hExcel.Range titleRange = (hExcel.Range)xlsWorksheet.Columns.get_Item(1,27); 
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far in terms of accessing the excel sheet and reading cell values?

Comment: How do you want to search? Want an excel formula? You want to write Macro? or you want to do it from C#?

Comment: @cularis, I can open it in c#. i wann know is there any way to set a range from A1 to A27? and then i can get each cell value to mach keyword "currency". But from MSDN, I get nothing valuable information how to set the range from A1 to A27.

Comment: Could you edit your post to include your source?

Comment: @cularis, nothing from the code. I just stopped at the point how to search from A1 to A27. i tried to find from MSDN, just find one method get_range(), but it doesn't explain more. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.get_range(v=VS.80).aspx.

Comment: @Meet Agrawal, I wanna do it via C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the Range you're looking for this way:

```
xlsWorksheet.Range("A1:A27")
```

then you can use the Find methods as explained here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a(v=vs.80).aspx

In your code this can be applied as follows (if there is only one occurrence of the string you are looking for):

```
Excel.Range firstFind = null; 

currentFind = titleRange.Find("apples", missing,
    Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, 
    Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, false,
    missing, missing); 
if (currentFind != null)
    String cellAddress = currentFind.get_Address(false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, false, System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
```

Comment: it works. thanks. But from my VS2008, it's like this  hExcel.Range titleRange = xlsWorksheet.get_Range("A1","A27");   I have update in my code

Comment: It should work both ways. The second argument is optional and I usually use the single string version, but the result should be exactly the same.

Comment: eh? why my vs2008 told me it cannot find the function and suggest me to use get_Range? it may framework problem?

Comment: You're right. I took a look at my code and in fact the optional parameters passed to office by C# must be specified even if they are not used. In particular you have to pass System.Reflection.Missing.Value for every optional parameter that you do not use (or just do it the way you are doing).